# How to make an inline-block parent's width be wrapped around it's children?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `div` with `display: inline-block` and two floated child `div`s. When there is enough space for them to be placed next to each other the parent `div`'s height and width are totally determined by the children.

But when the space is insufficient - making the child wrap to the next line and the elements be stacked vertically, the parent `div`'s width remains as it was just before the children stacked instead of adapting to the size of the largest child.

How can I solve this so the parent still wraps instead of having a width that is too large?

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acs3c3qs/)

```
<div id="parent">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

```
#parent {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

div > div {
    float: left;
}

div > div:first-child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow
}

div > div:last-child {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by not clearing the floats and as far as I've been able to read, there's no direct solution to do this in a fully responsive way without using JavaScript.

But with fixed dimensions, there is an approach that will clear the floats and wrap the parent :

http://jsfiddle.net/cfL491Lc/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 555px) {
    div > div:last-child {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

With the following logic : breakpoint = width of divs + padding + margin on body + 19px scrollbar.

If there's no scrollbar present, it will wrap a bit too early but that's the limitation of media queries. Depending on the surrounding content (especially the total height) another query might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting your question. In the code which you gave the outer div's height and width are determined by the inner divs

**when stacked horizontally :**

outer width = sum of inner widths
outer height = greatest of inner heights

```html
<div style="width:auto;height:auto;display: inline-block; border: solid 2px; padding: 10px; background-color: #aaaaaa;">

    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow;">
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; width: 80px; height: 30px; background-color: blue;">
    </div>


</div>
```

**When stacked vertically**

outer height= sum of inner heights
outer width= greatest of inner widths

```html
<div style="width:auto;height:auto;display: inline-block; border: solid 2px; padding: 10px; background-color: #aaaaaa;">

    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow;">
    </div>
<br>
    <div style="float: left; width: 80px; height: 30px; background-color: blue;">
    </div>


</div>
```

What do you want to change in this?

Comment: The width is **not** the greater of the childrens DIV. (the blue one - in my original code). It is too wide.

Comment: @ThomasAJ I think this will be some browser compatibility issue. Please provide screenshot of the output that you see, because i believe what you are seeing is not what i am seeing . Screenshot will help me understand the actual case. thanks.

Comment: @Shikkediel yes i introduced a <br> to stack it vertically. But us you can see above the first code snippet does not have a <br>